# Setting up a Typescript interface for a Redux action (Type '...' has no call signatures)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I'm starting to explore both Typescript and Redux+Typescript. I've been bouncing around lots of different resources and frankly i'm feeling a bit in over my head regarding what i'm trying to resolve below. I setup my interface in redux, named its parameters, and thought that would be enough. Unfortunately, when I tried to blatantly create type errors nothing was triggered. I added `alertActions.Parameters` to `setAlert` just for the heck of it.

I'm going to take a break and re-explore this later. Though, I am really curious how one would correctly handle this situation, it would certainly give me a more focused avenue to dig into.

the error I'm getting at this point: `Type 'Parameters' has no call signatures.`

**React Component**

```
import * as alertActions from '../../redux/actions/alert';

type Props = {
  format: 'login' | 'register';
  setAlert: alertActions.Parameters;
  register: any;
  login: any;
  isAuthenticated: boolean;
};

const Form = ({
  format,
  setAlert,
  register,
  login,
  isAuthenticated,
}: Props) => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    username: '',
    email: '',
    password: '',
    password2: '',
  });
...
// Type 'Parameters' has no call signatures. <--- Error
setAlert('Passwords do not match', 'danger');

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { ...alertActions, ...authActions })(
  Form
);
```

**Redux Action**

```
export enum AlertTypes {
  success = 'success',
  failure = 'failure',
  danger = 'danger',
  other = 'other',
}

export enum Scope {
  local = 'local',
  global = 'global',
}

export interface Parameters {
  msg: string;
  alertType: AlertTypes;
  scope: Scope;
  timeout: number;
}

export const setAlert = ({
  msg,
  alertType,
  scope = Scope.local,
  timeout = 10000,
}: Parameters) => (dispatch) => {
  const id = uuidv4();
  dispatch({
    type: SET_ALERT,
    payload: { msg, alertType, scope, id },
  });

  setTimeout(() => dispatch({ type: REMOVE_ALERT, payload: id }), timeout);
};
```